# Can google inbox on iPhone NOT show contact pictures

Tags: iphone, google

I am using [the google inbox app for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/inbox-by-gmail-inbox-that/id905060486?mt=8). Is it possible to set it up, so that it does not show pictures of people who is writing to me?
I need to recieve work relevant emails from persons whos profile pictures I find offensive, and do not want to look at.

I have been through all the settings I could find and I don't know of a search term or documented feature to allow this

Comment: [Mailbox](http://www.mailboxapp.com/) is really nice.

Comment: Are you open to a solution where no images are shown?

Comment: @bmike: Yes - I would be very happy, if no profile pictures were shown at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing their photos in your saved contact so that your photo of them shows up instead.

Comment: I do not know why this was downvoted. It is not the solution(I have not tested if it works yet), I was hoping for, but it could be the only option.

Comment: Unfortunately, `gmail app` and `google inbox` does not use the informations from the contacts app. The pictures are only taken from the google accounts.

Comment: Aw, that's a bummer. Hopefully, you find a response soon. I'm having issues getting photos on my non-photo email contacts; total opposite! Haha.