# Google Inbox Does Not Display My Contact Photo

Tags: email, photos, google

When I send e-mails through my regular Gmail address, my contact photo appears. When I send e-mails through a third-party domain associated with my e-mail inbox, my contact photo does not appear.

I would like to set up Google Inbox to show my photo when I use my third-party e-mail address. This is [basically the flip side of another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188047/can-google-inbox-on-iphone-not-show-contact-pictures) but I want to change things as the sender and not as the receiver.

Comment: I've linked this to the other answer. It's far better to link questions as opposed to answers. if the answers are similar or identical - so much the better, but they don't have to be so linking the questions is best.

Comment: @bmike You actually mean that you have linked the answer to my question here instead of linked this to the other answer.